# DialogFragment over keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, dialogfragment

I got a login Activity with EditText.

The user starts typing and the keyboard is shown.

After some time I'm trying to show a DialogFragment (Over the entire *activity* **AND** the *keyboard*)

The problem is that the keyboard gets disappear.

Is there a way to show the dialog Over the activity and the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

When you show your dialog try to add this code as well :

**Show your keyboard on runtime**

```
InputMethodManager manager= (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
manager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

Comment: I don't want to show it (again), I want the dialog to be over it